# Get Data from Mysql instead XML?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, xml

hey i have this javascript for a bubble up... this script gets InfoID and InfoData tags from an xml file...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function ( ) {
    // Get the XML data from your file
    $.get('scores.xml', function( data ) {

        // Because we've given jQuery the XML datatype, we can jump straight to finding the element.    
        $(data).find('Game').each( function ( ) {

            // The current object now holds a single "GAME" - find the elements we need
            var game_id = $(this).find('InfoID').text( );
            var game_info = $(this).find('InfoData').text( );

            // Create the popup.
            $('.'+game_id).CreateBubblePopup({
                    position : 'left', align : 'center',
                    innerHtml: game_info,
                    innerHtmlStyle: { color:'#FFFFFF', 'text align':'center' },
                    themeName: 'all-black',
                    themePath: 'images/jquerybubblepopup-themes'
            });
        }); // end of each
    }, 'xml'); // The 'xml' tells jQuery to expect XML back from the request
});
</script>
```

i need to make this script get data from Database table instead of xml.

i have the same InfoID and InfoData rows in a table in my database...

i use this php script to get data from db:

```
<?php
    // Connect to database server
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "asnaeb") or die (mysql_error ());

    // Select database
    mysql_select_db("scores") or die(mysql_error());

    // SQL query
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM latest";

    // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

    // Loop the recordset $rs
    // Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { 

       // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)?>
      <?php echo $row['Header'].""; ?>
      <?php echo $row['Row'].""; ?>
      <?php echo $row['Date'].""; ?>
      <?php echo $row['Time'].""; ?>
      <?php echo $row['AwayTeam'].""; ?>
      <?php echo $row['Score'].""; ?>
      <?php echo $row['HomeTeam'].""; ?>
      <?php echo $row['Other'].""; ?>
      <?php echo $row['InfoID'].""; ?>
      <?php echo $row['InfoData'].""; ?>

<?php } mysql_close(); ?>
```

any idea how i can do that? so i can remove my xml file and use database :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not convert your mysql data into XML? Or, better yet, json?

Comment: I think John has the right idea. Instead of just echoing all the data in the while loop, have it echo the data formatted as xml (or json -- I also would favor this) so you'd only need to make minimal changes to the javascript.

Comment: i was using xml for everything, i recently changed and started using database...so i want to make my whole site get info from database and remove xml... and i'm still a beginner in PHP stuff :)

Comment: Meh: you still need some sort of container transfer the records to the web browser. PHP may be able to perform a query and have instant access to variables with the data, but you can't just send objects to the web browser. The data must be serialized (put into text format), sent to the browser, and then deserialized back into objects that javascript understands. That means you still need to use JSON, XML, or some other format which holds your serialized data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ajax post with a seperate callback function and return json data from your php script.

Give this a shot:

```
// try this for your javascript
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function ( ) {
    function getGameInfo() {
  $.post("path/to/phpScript.php", 
   // this is the success callback
   function (json) {
    // this calls the function with the returned data
    parseReturnedData(json);
  });
  return false;
};

// process json data to set your game_id and game_info vars
function parseReturnedData(data) {
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  var game_id = obj.InfoID;
  var game_info = obj.InfoData;
}

// Create the popup.
$('.'+game_id).CreateBubblePopup({
  position : 'left', align : 'center',
  innerHtml: game_info,
  innerHtmlStyle: { color:'#FFFFFF', 'text align':'center' },
  themeName: 'all-black',
  themePath: 'images/jquerybubblepopup-themes'
});
</script>

// try this for your php file
<?php

    // declare vars
    $response = array();

    // Connect to database server
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "asnaeb") or die (mysql_error ());

    // Select database
    mysql_select_db("scores") or die(mysql_error());

    // SQL query
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM latest";

    // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

    // Loop the recordset $rs
    // Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysql_fetch_array
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { 

       // Write the value of the column FirstName (which is now in the array $row)?>
      $response['Header'] = $Header;
      $response['Row'] = $Row;
      $response['Date'] = $Date;
      $response['Time'] = $Time;
      $response['AwayTeam'] = $AwayTeam;
      $response['Score'] = $Score;
      $response['HomeTeam'] = $HomeTeam;
      $response['Other'] = $Other;
      $response['InfoID'] = $InfoID;
      $response['InfoData'] = $InfoData;

    } 

    echo json_encode($response);



    mysql_close(); 

?>
```

Comment: i appreciate your help mate! but, i am a beginner in PHP :( can u tell me what should i do? ( for a noob :P )